# pydrive.auth.RefreshError: Access token refresh failed: invalid_grant: Token has been expired or revoked

Tags: python, pydrive

so I was building a project which included me saving some in google drive and this is part of the code I used

```
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LoadCredentialsFile("mycreds.txt")
if gauth.credentials is None:
    gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
elif gauth.access_token_expired:
    gauth.Refresh()
else:
    gauth.Authorize()
gauth.SaveCredentialsFile("mycreds.txt")
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
```

It worked fine for a some days but then I started getting this error

```
pydrive.auth.RefreshError: Access token refresh failed: invalid_grant: Token has been expired or revoked.
```

It came from the  `gauth.Refresh()` line so does anyone know why this happened and how to fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem with `pydrive2`. The issue is caused by a revokation of your GDrive.

Try to delete the `credentials.json` in your root directory and authenticate once more.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem I fixed it some time ago but forgot to post the answer here

Comment: It keeps happening... Any Idea why my credentials keep being invalid?

Comment: For me didn't work by deleting credentials.json but if I removed mycreds.txt then I was able to relog in to g drive and then worked. Not sure if it will stay working yet.

Answer (score 2):

I tried removing `settings.yaml` and run the code again, it should ask you to "login" to your google account. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Let remove content of mycreds.txt first.

Then you have to create a settings.yaml file and set `get_refresh_token` is `True`

This is the setting file that I am using, hope it help

```
client_config_backend: 'settings'
client_config:
  client_id: "<copy client_id from client_secrets.json here>"
  client_secret: "<copy client_secret from client_secrets.json here>"

get_refresh_token: True
save_credentials: True
save_credentials_backend: 'file'
save_credentials_file: 'mycreds.txt'

oauth_scope:
  - "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
```